# Environment variables returning undefined when connecting Firebase Firestore to a node.js server hosted on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, heroku

I am quite new to the node.js way of doing things coming from using PHP and SQL to do everything. I was recently trying to set up a node server on Heroku in order to do some back end logic on my google firestore database.

I didn't want my private key to be publically accessible as a file and I saw that the easiest way was to store the variables as environment variables and use them to set up the certificate to initialise firebase-admin from a previous stack overflow question.

I have now tried to set this up and hosting it on heroku.  Having defined my environment variables I double checked that the names are correct and have been set by heroku config:set and then checking using heroku config.  I would show this but it obviously contains my private key!

So when i try to run this segment of code:

```js
//requires firebase module
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
const private_key = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID;
console.log(private_key);
//initialises a firebase app with the credential
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    "private_key": process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    "client_email": process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    "project_id": process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    "private_key_id": process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://MY_APP.firebaseio.com"
});
//get access to firestore from initialised app
var db = admin.firestore();
```

With MY_APP changed out from what it is in the source code.

So when i run this and console log the key I get:

[[image: console log of error caused by undefined variable][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhrL1.png)

I am sorry if this is a trivial problem, as I say I am definitely a beginner with node.  I have done a bit with the HTTP module for handling some requests but not connecting up to firebase.  Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post text in screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @Chris Thanks!  Sorry for that, cheers I will make sure to post it as text not an image in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku config:set` sets environment variables *on Heroku*, but `heroku local` runs your application on your local machine:

> Heroku Local is a command-line tool to run [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)-backed apps. It is installed automatically as part of the [Heroku CLI](https://cli.heroku.com/). Heroku Local [reads configuration variables from a .env file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#add-a-config-var-to-your-env-file). Heroku Local makes use of [node-foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman) to accomplish its tasks.

`heroku local` will automatically read a file called `.env` and set environment variables for you based on what it finds there. This file should [not be tracked by Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#add-a-config-var-to-your-env-file) (it's for your local environment, not for Heroku, and as you mentioned it will contain sensitive information that shouldn't be checked in anyway).

If you want to [copy a configuration variable that you currently have on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file) you can add it to your `.env` by running

```
heroku config:get CONFIG-VAR-NAME -s >> .env
```

(There are actually many ways to set environment variables on your local machine, and any of them will work with `heroku local`. If you prefer another method, go for it.)

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I see now, thank you so much for the extra tips as well I'll make sure to bear that in mind for when I am next running it locally.  I was having a silly moment I never wanted to be running it locally in the first place, thanks for spotting it !!